# 1 mod-rewrite block for multiple php pages

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two detail pages:

```
 www.mymichiganforeclosures.com/detail.php?kfld=address_City_state_zip

 www.mymichiganforeclosures.com/landcontractdetail.php?kfld=address_city_state_zip
```

I need one mod_rewrite parameter to pass the php page name as a parameter, and the second parameter to be passed as kfld look up parameter.

The following .htaccess works for detail.php:

```
options -multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+detail\.php\?kfld=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ /detail.php?kfld=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

What I want is:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/(*)etail\.php\?kfld=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ /$1etail.php?kfld=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Is this possible in .htaccess?

OK!  What about this:

```
if foreclosures
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+detail\.php\?kfld=([^\s&]+) [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ /%1.html? [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ /detail.php?kfld=$1 [L,NC,QSA]  
else
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+LandContractsDetail\.php\?kfld=([^\s&]+) [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ /%1.html? [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ /LandContractsDetail.php?kfld=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/LandContractsDetail\.php\?kfld=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /landcontracts/%1.html? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^landcontracts/([^.]+)\.html$ /LandContractsDetail.php?kfld=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/detail\.php\?kfld=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /foreclosures/%1.html? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^foreclosures/([^.]+)\.html$ /detail.php?kfld=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: tried that code but got the following errored output...        http://www.mymichiganforeclosures.com/detail-2154-Crystal-Cove-Dr-Allegan-MI-49010.html

Comment: this is what it is supposed to do:     http://www.mymichiganforeclosures.com/2154-Crystal-Cove-Dr-Allegan-MI-49010.html    But instead it goes to index page...

Comment: Would it be better to try multiple codeblocks?  One for detail.php and a separate one for landcontractdetail.php?

Comment: yes that can be done too. But what should be `.html` URLs in both cases?

Comment: outputted url should be  mymichiganforeclosures.com/address-city-state-zip.html in either case - it doesn't matter, as pages have specific wording on them...

Comment: No but how would rules know whether `/address-city-state-zip.html` be handled by `landcontractdetail.php` OR by `detail.php`?

Comment: is there a possible if statement based upon loaded page?

Comment: Page load happens after `.htaccess` rules. Logic can be based on URI/host/query-string etc and your URI is just `/address-city-state-zip.html`

Comment: Don't place code in comments, it should be in edited question.

Comment: What do you mean by `if foreclosures` how to check that condition?

Comment: The problem is that I have two separate index pages, LandcontractIndex.php which writes LandContractDetail.php, and another index.php page which writes detail.php.  Both use the same directory and database, therefore, I am unable to use the foreclosures/*.html and landcontracts/*.html because the code and db are all in one directory...

Comment: I suspect you don't understand rewrite mechanism completely. Pretty URL can very well be `foreclosures/*.html and landcontracts/*.html` without impacting rest of the things.

Comment: Ok but, will it write using the separate and specific php objects?

Comment: I have two separate scripts, how do I map both to one .htaccess.  Maybe we should take this to chat...

Comment: Tried it and got error.  click on this: http://www.mymichiganforeclosures.com/detail-2154-Crystal-Cove-Dr-Allegan-MI-49010.html

Comment: your HTML URL will be: `http://www.mymichiganforeclosures.com/foreclosures/2154-Crystal-Cove-Dr-Allegan-MI-49010.html`

Comment: got the following error:                                              Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, xxx.xxx@xx.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log

Comment: [Thu Nov 21 15:31:56 2013] [alert] [client 66.249.64.3] /var/www/vhosts/mymichiganforeclosures.com/httpdocs/.htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters
[Thu Nov 21 15:32:03 2013] [alert] [client 66.249.64.5] /var/www/vhosts/mymichiganforeclosures.com/httpdocs/.htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters
[Thu Nov 21 15:32:19 2013] [alert] [client 5.255.253.90] /var/www/vhosts/mymichiganforeclosures.com/httpdocs/.htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters

Comment: There was a typo, I fixed it. Can you try

Comment: For css, js, images just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.